# Change Detection in Test for Dynamically Created Component

Tags: angularjs, angular, integration-testing, angular-upgrade

I am migrating an AngularJS app to Angular (1.6 to 4.0), and I'm struggling with dynamically created components in my tests. For example I have an integration test that creates an AngularJS component with a button that pops up an Angular modal (using `ngx-bootstrap`) that is created via `ComponentFactory.create`. The issue is that change detection does not trigger inside the modal within my tests. It works in the app itself. And other Angular 2 components work inside tests, but not those created dynamically.

Do I have something wrong in my setup to cause the dynamically created components to be hooked into the wrong zone, maybe? I've tried every combination of changes I can think of to no avail.

I worked up a plunkr with some simple embedded angular 2 components [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ijhzPQVdO43TTcn2S05x?p=preview).

To test it I find myself having to always trigger change detection manually [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9f6zhHUjsVwXuKrAWQv7?p=preview). Open `app/ng1/parent.spec.ts` where you can find the `doChangeDetection` function that should not be necessary.

Note that I'm using `UpgradeAdapter` instead of `downgradeComponent` because [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14263) indicates that non-dynamically created components would have broken change detection.

Comment: Can you provide plunker to reproduce it?

Comment: @yurzui It took a fair amount of work to create a little plunkr, but I finally succeeded. See the 2 links in my edits above. Thanks!

Comment: As far i know we always run `detectChanges()` in your angular tests.

Comment: I'm not using `componentRef.detectChanges()`, if that's what you mean. Before introducing Angular 4 no manual triggering of change detection was needed at all for a test like this. And the fact that it requires different commands to trigger change detection depending on whether the same component was created statically vs dynamically seems very fishy.